# Exporting provider functions and adhering object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

I have this code for **I18n**:

```
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import LngDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import i18n from 'i18next';

import common_en from "../locales/en/common.json";
import common_sv from "../locales/sv/common.json";

i18n
  .use(LngDetector)
  .init({
    resources: {
      en: {
        common: common_en
      },
      sv: {
        common: common_sv
      },
    },
  });
```

The above code wraps the root App like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  var root = document.getElementById('root');
  render(
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
        <App/>
    </I18nextProvider>,
    root,
  )
})
```

This pattern will be repeated many times in the code (there are `many React Apps instantiated throughout the whole application`). Is there any way to export the first part, so it can be used something like this:

```
render(
  <ExportedI18nextProvider>
      <App/>
  </ExportedI18nextProvider>,
  root,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//ExportedI18nextProvider.js

export default class ExportedI18nextProvider extends React.Component{

    render(){
        var root = document.getElementById('root');
        return(
            <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
                 {this.props.children} //children prop accessed here i.e. App Component
            </I18nextProvider>
        )
    }
}
```

And here one can import it to reuse the code.

```
import ExportedI18nextProvider from 'some_path_to_ExportedI18nextProvider';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    render(
        <ExportedI18nextProvider>
            <App/>//this will be passed as children prop
        </ExportedI18nextProvider>,
        root,
      )
  })
```